# CKeditor - Custom Colors

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

Is there a way to make a custom color list, like this one: http://prntscr.com/1ndyrb

I wanna add custom colors to this list instead of these.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question makes no sense whatsoever... "I wanna add custom colors to this list instead of these." .... what list and what do you mean by these? Please stop a moment and think about the people trying to help you not just about what you want from your perspective.

Comment: @Christian The question is accurate, I don't get what's your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Set [config.colorButton_colors](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-colorButton_colors) to do this.